# stack rerange stack odd even

Tags: java, stack

I Write this method to rearranges the elements of two stacks in such a way that stack s1 contains only even integers and stack s2 contains only odd integers. and any zeroes should not stored in s1 or s2.

```
public static void rerange(stackl l1 , stackl l2)
{
    stackl tmp = new stackl();
    stackl tmp2 = new stackl();
    while(!l1.isEmptyS()) 
    {
        int x = l1.pop();
        if(x!=0 && x%2==0)
            tmp.push(x);
        else 
            tmp2.push(x);
    }
    while(!l2.isEmptyS())
    {
        int y = l2.pop();
        if(y!=0 && y%2==0)
            tmp.push(y);
        else 
            tmp2.push(y);
    }
    tmp.prints();
    System.out.println();
    tmp2.prints();
}
```

it works good but it sort ero also ,, how can i eliminate the 0s ?

here is the main method

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        stackl s1 = new stackl();
        stackl s2 = new stackl();
        s1.push(0);
        s1.push(2);
        s1.push(3);
        s1.push(5);
        s1.push(6);
        s1.prints();
        System.out.println();
        s2.push(1);
        s2.push(10);
        s2.push(9);
        s2.push(0);
        s2.push(15);
        s2.prints();
        System.out.println();
        rerange(s1,s2);
```

the output is :

```
6 5 3 2 0 
15 0 9 10 1 
10 2 6 
1 9 0 15 0 3 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is putting zero into the odd stack because of how you've written your if-statement:

```
if (x != 0 && x % 2 == 0)
    // x is non-zero and even
    tmp.push(x);
else
    // all other numbers (x is zero, or odd)
    tmp2.push(x);
```

When you lump both conditions in the initial check, the else picks up the negation of that.
Since logically `!(A && B)` is `!A || !B`, and your if case is "not zero and even", your else is effectively "zero or odd".

What you need to do is check for zero-ness first, and not push anything in that case:

```
if (x != 0) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        tmp.push(x);
    } else {
        tmp2.push(x);
    }
}
```